# Why didn't Michael Scott appear in the Q&A panel in the Finale episode of The Office?

Tags: the-office

In the Finale episode of The Office, the Scranton Cultural Center hosts a public Q&A panel of the employees of Dunder Mifflin.  Most of the regular characters return for this after several months, even Kevin, who was fired, and Stanley, who had retired.  Yet no mention is made at all of Michael Scott.  Why wasn't Michael Scott invited?

I'm also curious for an out-of-universe explanation; was Steve Carrel invited to appear one last time?

Comment: I could ask a separate question for the out-of-universe explanation, if it seems appropriate.

Comment: ... And Holly, didn't anyone else miss Holly?

Comment: Well there were other flaws too. For many years he was close with Dwight and felt close to the other workers, yet he doesn't invite any of them to his wedding or even keep in touch via email or something about updates in his life? That seemed out of character for him, for me anyway. If he did mature, I felt he should have apologized to Toby for the horrible way he treated him for so many years.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [The Office Wiki](http://theoffice.wikia.com/wiki/Finale):

> "I figured the character would go back and visit everybody, but he
>   wouldn't do it on camera at this point. I think he had grown past the
>   idea of being in the documentary, that was my take on it. That
>   [Michael Scott] had said goodbye to that aspect of his life, that
>   that's not what was important to him. I just thought, yeah he'd go
>   back and visit, but he wouldn't want the camera crew to be documenting
>   it." —Steve Carell, explaining his hesitation to return to The Office.

Comment: That's so... out of character for him... he's *always* trying to grab the spot light. But kudos to Michael if he matured a bit in that area. :)

Comment: That doesn't really fit to the "[..] children grow up and marry each other [..]"-comment of Michael's. But he was very emotional at that point and maybe forgot about his "grown past" for a second.